# Compare Thrust fill with kernel launch speed

Tags: cuda, thrust

I've observed that filling an array in a kernel is much faster than using `thrust::fill`. To test it, I wrote a simple program:

```
const uint N = 1e6; 

__device__ uint Val2[N];

__global__ void set0()
{
    uint index = __mul24(blockIdx.x, blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    if (index < N)
    {
       Val2[index] = 0;
    }

}


int main()
{
    thrust::device_vector<uint> Val1(N);
    for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
    {
       thrust::fill(Val1.begin(), Val1.end(),0);
       int numThreads = 512;
       uint numBlocks =  (uint)ceil( N / (double)numThreads);
       set0 << < numBlocks, numThreads >> >();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now there are two questions:

1. According to Nsight figures, `thrust::fill` takes around 1200 us to fill the array while `set0` kernel completes it in 44 us. What is the problem with my code that `thrust::fill` is so slow and if it's truly much slower than kernel, why it should be used at all?
2. It seems that the  `set0` kernel doesn't launch in the fist loop i.e. `i=0` (at least Nsight doesn't show it in CUDA Launches list). But it does in the second loop. What is the problem?

I'm running the program on a Tesla K20X. CUDA version is 7.0.

Thanks in advance.

Update (based on @RobertCrovella comment)

Test results for CUDA8.0+GTX 1050TI:

[Test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVbOY.png)

Comment: kernel launches are asynchronous, and immediately at the point of the second `set0` kernel launch, your program exits.  You should use a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after the thrust fill and after the `set0` kernel.  Regarding timing, I took your code and ran it on a Pascal Titan X with CUDA 8 on linux, and `nvprof` shows that the `set0` kernel takes 10us and the thrust::fill kernel also takes 10us.  I see no difference.  Windows WDDM may be messing things up, you may be getting some start-up overhead, and you may simply be misinterpreting the data, that you haven't shown.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The code I run is exactly the same of what I've sent (except headers). Based on what you told I guessed that the problem would be with the version of CUDA and Thrust library so I checked the code on a different machine running CUDA 8.0 on GTX-1050 TI. The NSIGHT shows that kernel complete the code in 14 ms (not 14 us) and `thrust::fill` in 162 ms (far slower compared to K20X but with same speed ratios). So that's not the problem. Refer to misinterpretation, I added NSIGHT results for CUDA8.0+1050 TI. I don't know what kind of misinterpretation may be occurred.

Comment: I guess this is on windows.  Are you building debug builds or release builds?

Comment: I'm quite sure the code  you have shown is not what you are running with that profiler output.  The profiler output for `set0` kernel shows 195313 blocks of 512 threads each.  But your posted code would not and does not compute that.  It computes 1954 blocks of 512 threads each, to match `N` of `1e6`. My guess is you are analyzing the performance of debug builds here, which is not sensible.

Comment: A side note: There are some thrust functions which are not maximally optimal (e.g. NVIDIA's CUB does better). But - `thrust::fill()` is most likely not one of those.

Comment: Thank you very much @RobertCrovella. I changed the solution configuration to "Release" and now thrust::fill is 40% faster than kernel. I'd the same problem with thrust::sort and it have been solved by your comment. `thrust::sort` execution time in one sample program decreased from 21ms to 900 us (1e6 pairs). I didn't expect so huge gap between these two configurations (the gap between kernel launches is mush smaller comparing two configurations). please make your comment an answer, so that I can accept it